# How to integrate Google Realtime Playground with Android App?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, real-time, google-drive-realtime-api, real-time-updates

I am in serious need to any tutorial for integrating Google Realtime Playground with Android App.
I know it is possible as people has done this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodow.realtime.android.playground

I've found the code for the same on GitHub: 
https://github.com/goodow/realtime-android-playground

But code shared here is also not complete.
Please help me with some useful links and tutorials.

Regards,
RJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official library that wraps Realtime functionalities for Android for now. What goodow does is to wrap a `WebView` and wrap non-native calls.

See also the sources on the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/goodow/realtime-android-playground/tree/master/src/main/java/com/goodow/realtime/android/playground).